# How to convert a NULL in SQL server 2012 to a blank(n/a) value in oracle using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I'd like to thank you in advance for all of your responses. I have a small issue here where I can't seem to get a NULL value in the sql server database to read as a n/a value in oracle. So right now the column in reference in oracle is set 'yes' to nullable. I wrote a small code to convert NULL in sql developer to a " " in oracle which in turn would return an n/a but does not see to work:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    // Set into INSERT the values SELECTED
    psinst.setString(1, rs.getString("MATERIAL_NUMBER"));
    psinst.setString(2, rs.getString("BATCH_NUMBER"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER"));
    VendorBatchNumber = rs.getString("VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER");
    if (VendorBatchNumber == null || VendorBatchNumber == "" || VendorBatchNumber == "NULL") {
        VendorBatchNumber = "";
    } else {
        VendorBatchNumber = rs.getString("VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER");
    }
    psinst.setString(3, VendorBatchNumber);
}
```

So basically I am setting VendorBatchNumber the variable to the value in the sql server database. when I write the following line:

```
System.out.println(rs.getString("VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER"));
```

NULL actually gets printed to the console. Under that assumption the following if statement from above:

```
if (VendorBatchNumber == null || VendorBatchNumber == "" || VendorBatchNumber == "NULL"){
    VendorBatchNumber = "";
}
```

should return "" which in turn would produce n/a. For some reason this if statement does not hold true. I know I am missing something small here. Can someone help me with this? Thanks again in advance and please let me know if more information is needed.

When I use the following sql statement:

```
select COALESCE(VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER , 'n/a') as VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER FROM MATERIAL_BATCH;
```

I still get the same NULL values. it seems like COALESCE does not recognize NULL.

[image: Vendor Batch Number]

Is there another way to do this? Also I am trying to convert using SQL developer for oracle. 
Thanks
Sonny

Comment: You should probably check for DBNull.Value. so your if statement will become `if (VendorBatchNumber == DBNull.Value || VendorBatchNumber == "" || VendorBatchNumber == "NULL"){
                VendorBatchNumber = "";
            }`

Comment: I suppose you are asking @Harsh ? :)

Comment: @Harsh Thanks for your reply. For some reason Java does not recognize the statement DBNull.Value. Is there an implementation that must be done before I can use it or should it be a built in value?

Comment: @Sonny No problem :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That won't work in java, it was for .net. Are you sure your database contains NULL values and not the string "NULL" because if it contains actual nulls, coalesce() should work fine.

Comment: @Harsh I noticed coalesce() does not work either. If the value is of string "NULL" shouldn't I be able to compare it as I did above in my if statement?

Comment: Maybe not. Try using .equals() instead of == for testing equality.

Comment: @Harsh. yes. the .equals did the trick. Thank you so much. If you post it as an answer to this question I will give you the green check mark. :-)

Comment: @Sonny, I am glad it worked. Posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` check for reference equality, you should use `.equals()` to check for value equality.

```
if (VendorBatchNumber==null || VendorBatchNumber.equals("") || VendorBatchNumber.eqauls("NULL")){
    VendorBatchNumber = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use isnull()

```
select isnull(Quantity,'the value you want in place of null value')
```

Comment: When I try this statement: select isnull(VENDOR_BATCH_NUMBER,'test')
  FROM [dbo].[MATERIAL_BATCH_VIEW] it gives me the same NULL value. Is there a way to read the string NULL and then convert it to a blank? I am thinking this is a hardcoded NULL

Comment: iif(Quantity='NULL',Quantity,' ')

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COALESCE() to convert a null value to whatever you. Like this

```
SELECT ProductName,UnitPrice*COALESCE(Quantity,0))
```

FROM Product

if Quantity is null COALESCE() function will return 0, for your case you can replace the 0 by ""

Comment: -Thanks for your response. When I tried this statement: select coalesce(vendor_batch_number,'')  FROM MATERIAL_BATCH; It gives me a column with the exact same values still showing NULL. is there a way to identify the string NULL